# Predicting Imagick::thumbnailImage() dimensions

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, thumbnails

What is a fast way to tell what dimensions an `Imagick` instance will become when you call `Imagick::thumbnailImage($w, $h)` on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an algorithm for finding the dimensions that `Imagick::thumbnailImage($w, $h)` gives that handles all possible situations with 100% accuracy. (e.g. cases where `$w` or `$h` are `0`, etc.)  So, I made this function:

```
function thumbSize($pic, $thumbW, $thumbH) {
    //make a white image of the same size
    $picsize = $pic->getImageGeometry();
    $whitepic=new Imagick();
    $whitepic->newImage($picsize['width'], $picsize['height'], "white");
    $whitepic->thumbnailImage($thumbW, $thumbH);
    return $whitepic->getImageGeometry();
}
```

Sadly, it has to resize an image to work; it is many times slower than an algorithm-based solution.  But it works.

If anyone else has a better answer, I'll check it instead.

Comment: You might create the image with a format of "GRAY" to speed it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this...

```
# 3:2 format
$w = 120; # desired width
$h = 80; # desired height

$r = 640 / 480; # current width / height 4:3 format

if ($w / $h < $r)
    $w = $h * $r;
else
    $h = $w / $r;

echo $w, $h; # 120x90 4:3 format
```

If you give dimensions (current w&h, desired w&h, and the one produced by imagick) it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably one of the dimensions, either width or height, will be exactly the dimension called for in your thumbnail call. You can determine which one by comparing the ratios of thumbW/width and thumbH/height, the smaller of the two will be used. The thumbnail dimensions are nominally width*ratio and height*ratio. The only thing left is to convert to integers, and the choices are round up, round down, and round to nearest. I don't know which one Imagick uses, but it shouldn't be hard to experiment and see which one matches.

I also don't know what happens when both ratios are less than one, i.e. when the original image is smaller than the requested thumbnail size. A simple experiment should clear that up too.

Sorry for not performing the experiments myself, but PHP isn't in my repertoire.